# Incorporate fasttext vectors in tf.keras embedding layer?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, embedding, fasttext

Fasttext could handle OOV easily, i.e., it could be assumed that `emb = fasttext_model(raw_input)` always holds. However, I am not sure how I could build this layer into `tf.keras` embedding. I couldn't simply load the matrix into `Embedding` because in that way the OOV couldn't be handled. Is there a walkaround that I could use `fasttext_model` in a `tf.keras` model?

Comment: Did you try this approach? It seems to work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62743531/using-gensim-fasttext-model-with-lstm-nn-in-keras